# AngularJS get data from MySQL via a php file

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, http

here's my issue:

I did a very basic angularJS app which is supposed to get data from a php file and bind them into the scope. So the php file (linked to MySQL DB) output is:

```
[{"hum":"55.36","temp":"20.86","unixtime":"2015-10-29 17:39:42","coreid":"xxxxxx","moist":"0.02","volt":"4.30","soc":"114"},
{"hum":"55.33","temp":"20.84","unixtime":"2015-10-29 17:39:50","coreid":"xxxxxx","moist":"0.00","volt":"4.30","soc":"114"},
{"hum":"55.42","temp":"20.84","unixtime":"2015-10-29 17:39:58","coreid":"xxxxxx","moist":"0.02","volt":"4.30","soc":"114"}]
```

The app's code is:

```
var dashb = angular.module('dashboard', []);

//avoid cross domain issue
dashb.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);


dashb.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
         $http.get("http://www.domain.com/php_file_url.php")
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.hum = data.hum;

            })
            .error(function() {
                $scope.data = "error in fetching data";

            });


    }]);
```

But when I run it it doesn't work. I get no data. What do I do wrong? Thank you

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Your explanation of `it doesn't work` doesn't tell us anything

Comment: In the network tab I see nothing, literally :(

Comment: That really doesn't make sense. Without some debugging information not much anyone can do to help you

Comment: The only debug information I can get is this error in the console:
     Error: $injector:modulerr
     Module Error

Comment: well that's pretty important. Your app isn't initializing because of it. Need to figure out which module it refers to and read the full error

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you're getting data from your query, you just need to send it as JSON. Add this before the `echo $res;` line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also, in your code, change the following

```
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

to

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```